# draw figure(numbers) with for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, numbers, drawing

I'm just getting started with Java and my teacher asked me to draw the following shape of numbers:

```
123456654321
 2345665432
  34566543
   456654
    5665
     66
    5665
   456654
  34566543
 2345665432 
123456654321
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYMoM.png)

So far I was able to draw first line and part of the middle using this code:

```
 int sz = 6;

    for (int i =1;i<=sz;i++)
        System.out.print(i);
    for(int j =sz;j>1;j--)
        System.out.print(j);

    for(int i =1; i<=sz;i++){
        System.out.println(i);
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
```

I'm having trouble the rest of the middle body.
Can anyone help me out drawing that one, by using nested for loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go line by line,because after `println()`,you cannot go back there.

For the upper half of the pattern you can use this.

```
int sz = 6;

   for(int d = 1;d<=sz;d++){

    for (int i = d;i <= sz;i++) //for increasing numbers
        System.out.print(i);
    for(int j=sz;j>=d;j--)  //for decreasing numbers
        System.out.print(j);

    System.out.println(); //for newline

    for(int m=0;m<d;m++) // for spaces
        System.out.print(" ");
   }
```

Comment: This will print only the upper part. What about the lower part of the "hourglass"?

Comment: I did not want to do his assignment,I think the code I posted is enough guide to complete the assignment.After he tried,if he cannot achieve of course I can help,but at least first he should understand the first part of it and make some affort.

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to do the second part of my assignment following the logic of your code.

Answer (score 0):

First you build an array, then traverse the lines and build them:

```
int currentItem = 1;
int items[] = new int[12];
for (int index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    items[index] = (index < 6) ? currentItem++ : currentItem--;
}

for (int index2 = 0; index2 < 12; index2++) {
    String line = "";
    int limit = (index2 < 6) ? index2 : (12 - index2);
    for (int index3 = 0; index3 < items.length; index3++) {
        line += ((index3 >= limit) && (index3 < items.length - limit)) ? " " : items[index3];
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```